# Run sql query only for a specific time period

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to run my sql query only for 30 minutes in ssis using data flow task. After 30 minutes the source data should stop loading to the destination table. How can i achieve this. Will command timeout work for this?

Comment: see here..

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN

IF(RIGHT(RIGHT(GETDATE(),12),6) = ‘2:29PM’)

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job  N'<<Your job Name>>’ ;

END



https://ssisblog.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-implement-timer-in-ssis/

Comment: This one is better 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6135/how-to-stop-a-ssis-package-execution-from-code/